# Create a public profile page for specific roles only

Tags: 7, views, users

Here is what I am trying to do.

I used profile2 to create an employee profile type that only users with the user role of employee could fill out.

What I want to do with views ( which I am not even sure if its possible) is have views create a profile page for each employee with a path of about-us/[user:full-name] (a field I created for the employee profile) and only create it for employee user.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You can achive it by create a new permission (employee profile type) using hook_permission(https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7). After creating the permisssion go to admin/people/permissions and give the permission "employee profile type" to the employee role. After creating the VIEWS, go to your VIEW + PAGE SETTINGS + Click Access and then click permission and select the the created permission "employee profile type".

Comment: Given the [comment posted for an answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72081/create-public-profile-page-for-specific-roles-only#comment79030_72098), and the fact there isn't any explicit question, this question is too broad. (_I know I will have to use view blocks and then state that the blocks should only appear on pages with the path about-us/*_.) It's not just a matter of creating a profile page for employee users, but also giving to the profile page a path alias, and associate blocks to the profile page.

Comment: Notice that for a profile page, you don't need any block, or a path alias. The Profile2 module allows to create profile pages that are used only for specific roles.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you are looking for is to modify the URL structure. In my mind, View is for the layout. Since I assume you have a content type for Profile2 profiles, you can simply install [PathAuto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) and configure it so your URLs have that structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do that with views too.. I think you will need to use argument handling in views.
But only issue is the query argument should have more qualifying filter like drupal user id or employee id (if you are maintaining them).

This could go along with users full name field to make your url about-us/[user:fullname]/[user:uniqueid]

Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: I think I need more details... let me explain exactly what I am looking for and where my confusions lay.   Have a very unique design in mind for the employee profile pages.  I know I will have to use view blocks and then state that the blocks should only appear on pages with the path about-us/* what I am not sure on is what filters or relationships do I need in the views to make the proper information fill in and if for the view page will threat of about-us/[user:full-name] create pages for all employees?